# Error when running BeaconManager.bind inside a method ALTBeacon

Tags: android, altbeacon

My scanner class extends Application and implements BeaconConsumer. When I try to bind or unbind the BeaconManager I get a NullPointerException.

```
public class Scanner extends Application implements BeaconConsumer{
private BeaconManager beaconManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    try {
        super.onCreate();

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(" m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void startScan(long period){
    try {
        if (beaconManager==null) {
            beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(Scanner.this);
            beaconManager.bind(Scanner.this);
            beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(period);
            beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopScan(){
    beaconManager.unbind(Scanner.this);
}
```

I get the following error :

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.bind(org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: it works fine if I try to do this inside the onCreate() method itself.

Comment: when are you calling `startScan` ? Maybe you do before beaconManager was initialized?

Comment: I create a new Scanner object inside the onCreate() method in the MainActivity and run the startScan using a button

Comment: Then you can try to add a null-check `if(beaconManager == null) initBeaconManager();` and in that method you do the initialization of it

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: put a breakpoint at the line where you assign a value to the beaconManager variable. Confirm its value in the debugger

Comment: Between onCreate() and startScan() the beaconmanager turns to a null object,and reinitializing the object doesnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that there are multiple instances of the `Scanner` class running.  In general you should not ever manually create an instance of an Android Application class (one that extends Application).  You declare such a class in the AndroidManifest.xml, and let the Android OS instantiate it when it starts up the app.  If you manually instantiate the class by calling its constructor, the `onCreate()` method will not get called and the `beaconManager` will not get created.

If you want to get an instance of this class from an `Activity` so you can call methods like `startScan()` or `stopScan()` you can use:

`Scanner scanner = (Scanner) this.getApplication();`

Be careful, also, about two other issues with the way the code is written:

1. If you call `startScan()`, `stopScan()`, `startScan()`, nothing will happen on the second `startScan()` call because `beaconManager` will not be nil.  Scanning will not restart.
2. The call to `beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();` will fail if the asynchronous `bind(...);` call before it has not completed (usually it will not), causing the code to fall into the catch block.  An easy fix is to remove that call to `beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();` and simply move the `beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(period);` call before the call to `bind(...)`.